# Filtering an argus file

Tags: pcap, tcpdump, tshark

I'm utilizing argus against a pcap file and need to filter by datetime, source and destination IP, and port.  Currently, I can take a pcap file and convert to argus:

```
argus -r packet.pcap -w packet.argus
```

Then, to read and display argus data:

```
ra -r packet.argus
```

At this point, it seems that one can filter the argus data by my aforementioned parameters by using the *ra* command but I can't seem to find the correct syntax.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

info in
https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-ra/

so an example from a batch file I used...
ra -s {column names} -r $l.ra > $l.txt

also suggest adding state and flags, giving;
ra -s stime proto saddr sport daddr dport state -nzr $l.ra > $l.txt

Comment: note that after installing argus on fedora you experience core dumps and may need to comment out the ARGUS_BIND_IP lines in /etc/argus.conf to resolve the issue due to a bug